# ExecuteQuery returns empty collection when there is only a single result

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm using a auto created Linq to SQL Classes dbml and I have created the model class by hand. It should select all Schemas from a SQL Server, which is working when there are more than one Schema in the Database, but when there is only a single result I get an empty collection as result.

I have also exact the same models for Tables and Views which are showing me the same behavior.

What am I missing in order to get also a single result?

**Code:**

```
var schemaQuery = "SELECT Distinct
                   SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as Name,
                   schema_id as Id
                   from sys.tables 
                   Order by Name"

var context = new DbDataContext();
var schemas = context.ExecuteQuery<Schema>(schemaQuery);
```

**Model class:**

```
public class Schema
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    [ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_id", DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_name", DbType = "NVarChar(MAX)")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Results:**
Database with dbo and System schemas

[image: linq to sql results]

Databse with only dbo schema

[image: linq to sql no results]

Comment: You column-attribute-storage-mappings in code do not match with your query. Code mappings map to `_id` and `_name`, while your query results in columns `Id` and `Name`. Do you get an empty collection, or a single empty item in the collection?

Comment: @Maarten as I read on MSDN Documentation the Storage in the ColumnAttribute is only a private storage field to hold the value from a column. So that should not be the Query Result mappings? I have edited the question with the debug results.

Comment: Are result screenshots made for sys.tables query? Why does name contain schema name instead of table name then?

Comment: @FireAlkazar that was only a copy paste error, i have these queries for tables, schemas and users. The result of each query is the same, if it is only 1 result i don't get anything. When there are more then 1 result i get the correct results back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact issue you have, but it will of course return nothing if there are no table in the database. If you want to select all schemas better use:

```
SELECT schema_id, name FROM sys.schemas
```